# How can I find the default datasource connection pool settings for Spring Boot?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am building an application that needs to connect to dynamic datasources. I have modified my configuration class to declare a data source as follows:

```
public DataSource adminDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .username(dataSourceUsername)
            .password(dataSourcePassword)
            .url(dataSourceUrl)
            .driverClassName(dataSourceDriver)
            .build();
}
```

However, if the application goes untouched, timeouts start occuring:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 73,378,871 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 73,378,871 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

I've added autoReconnect=true to the connection url, but this still appears to happen. None of this happens with a regular datasource configured through the property file. How can I change my datasource config to match the default connection pool settings to prevent these timeouts?

Comment: Copied from `DataSrouceBuilder` document:
`only a small set of common configuration properties are supported. To inject additional properties into the result you can downcast it`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I needed to add a validation query and testOnBorrow = true, which was the only difference from the original Datasource